# Vidyo Client In Event Room Link

Tags: ios, vidyo

Current we are passing the portalUri,username,password for a Send Login Event in iOS.

`(VidyoClientSendEvent(VIDYO_CLIENT_IN_EVENT_LOGIN, &event, sizeof(VidyoClientInEventLogIn))`

Wanting to know if passing the portalUri, roomKey, displayName, pin, clientType for
`VIDYO_CLIENT_IN_EVENT_ROOM_LINK` is a similar step to start a Vidyo conference call with an iOS application?  Just one is initiating or joining a room with username, passsword credintials, and the other is entering a room that has already been created?

`(VidyoClientSendEvent(VIDYO_CLIENT_IN_EVENT_ROOM_LINK, &event, sizeof(VidyoClientInEventRoomLink)));`

Answer (score 0):

VIDYO_CLIENT_IN_EVENT_LOGIN is an API call to login into the VidyoPortal. It does not join a room. And if you join a room after that, you will be joining as a registered user.

VIDYO_CLIENT_IN_EVENT_ROOM_LINK is an API to join a room. If you call this without login first, you will join as guest. If you call this after you login, you will be joining the room as a registered user.